# How to use multiple nested parentheses with exponents?

Tags: r, parentheses, exponent

I need to create a new variable in my data frame that is the output of an equation with many nested parentheses. Part of this equation is in the form of the last line below

```
temp=36  
Tc = 647.097    
( ( 1-273.15+temp )/Tc )^1.5
```

where `temp` will be a variable, and `Tc` will be a constant. However, when I run the code the result is always `NA`.

But, if I break the code down into the number that I know results from

```
( 1-273.15+temp )/Tc
```

and then add the exponent like so

```
-0.3649376^1.5
```

then the code works as it should.

Why is R not able to correctly output the calculation `( ( 1-273.15+temp )/Tc )^1.5` ?

And more importantly, how can I get R to give me the result of `( ( 1-273.15+temp )/Tc )^1.5` while retaining my use of objects for the constant and the variable?

I need to address this, because the full equation is even worse, where the problem I describe above is nested within itself:

```
e_sat_test <- Pc^( ( Tc/(273.15+temp ) ) * 
  ( a1*( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc ) + a2*( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc )^1.5 +
     a3*( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc )^3 + a4* ( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc )^3.5 +
    a5*( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc)^4 + a6*( (1-273.15+temp)/Tc )^7.5  ) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
-0.3649376^1.5
```

is interpreted as

```
-(0.3649376^1.5)
```

not

```
(-0.3649376)^1.5
```

because the exponent operator has a higher precedence. And when you take something to a .5 exponent that's like taking a square root and those aren't defined for simple numeric vectors in R (unless you want to use imaginary numbers). Your calculation is simply NaN for your data values because your result is not real. You might want to check your formula again,

Comment: `those aren't defined for negative numbers` ... actually, they _are_ defined, at least in terms of basic math theory, as imaginary numbers.  But, I also couldn't seem to get it to work using base R.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry. I should have been more precise. Yes, the roots of negative numbers would be imaginary. If you did `as.complex(-0.3649376)^1.5`, it would work. But R won't automatically jump to complex numbers without an explicit cast.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I went back to the original formula (it is for calculating vapor pressure deficit) I should have had the form: ( (1 - (273.15+temp) / Tc))^1.5

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation:](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html)

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why (-8)^(1/3) is NaN. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function pow for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result in many corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard. On many Unix-alike systems the command man pow gives details of the values in a large number of corner cases.